# CLS with Adsense Funding Choice

Tags: web, adsense, core-web-vitals, cls, fundingchoices

I have been struggling to get the CLS value down. CLS on my websites is mostly caused by Adsense ads and Funding Choice consent manager.

The funding choice consent notification causes CLS. It seems to load some icons which shift the content down. Does anyone have a suggestion how to avoid the icons to shift the layout?

Comment: There's some documentation on dealing with ads that cause CLS at https://web.dev/optimize-cls/#ads-embeds-and-iframes-without-dimensions

Comment: Thanks @RickViscomi. It seems font swap increases LCP a lot. But high CLS is still caused only by Google Funding Choice dialog.

Comment: Do you found any solution to this ?

Comment: @Ionik Unfortunately no. On another website, I do not have this challenge. It may also be something related to fonts in consent message. Funding Choice message and auto-ads are the main reasons for my non-optimal CLS value.